# Run cron jobs dynamically in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron

I want to run **cron jobs dynamically**.

Instead of putting a direct **@Scheduled** annotation like `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 3 * * *")` on the main function, I want to take cron expression in input and then schedule job according to the input given.

I have tried to use `CronExpression`, But it's not giving correct results.
Even for `cronExpression = "0 0/30 1 * * *"`, It's returning that cron expression is not valid.

Error that I am getting while using cronExpression is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you have 6 time parts, crontab has 5

Comment: cron tab has 5 parts but This one is also a valid cron expression if you want to schedule job using java with @Scheduled annotation.